# Can I merge only questions from another account?

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I have two Stack Exchange accounts, but I want one for questions (this one), and one for answers (the second one). In this account I have no answers at all.

Can I ask a moderator to merge all the questions (only questions!) from my second account to this account?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can I ask a moderator to merge all the questions (only questions!) from my second account to this account?

It is not something that's possible. Merges are full merges - there is no "only merge these bits".